# Old ECS tasks still referenced in new deploy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-cdk, aws-fargate

I have an application deployed to Fargate on ECS using CDK. The first time I deployed the stack worked fine. The task passed all the healthchecks and everything was good.

I then tried to use the [GitLab CD](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/cloud_deployment/#deploy-your-application-to-the-aws-elastic-container-service-ecs) integration which failed.

I destroyed the stack with (cdk destroy) and after cdk deploy the task isn't passing the healthchecks (Even though I see in the logs that the app is responding just fine to the requests). Moreover I noticed that the new cluster contains somehow the old references of the failed tasks of the previous stack.

Here is how it looks:

[image]

Any ideea on why this behaviour is happening? and/or how to solve it?

Comment: Provide your CDK code. Are you using CDK pipelines?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/Xfk5pxsD  || I am not using cdk pipelines, I am trying to make it work with gitlab CI/CD, and they have this template I referenced it in the question that when I try to use it it breaks the stack and even after cdk destroy and cdk deploy it doesn't work